# npm linked module listed as unmet dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm linking `my-lib` to see effects in `my-app` right away.

```
cd my-lib-folder
npm link

cd ../my-app-folder
npm link my-lib
```

This works as expected. Changes are picked up by `my-app` and I see the symlink in `node_modules`. My problem is that in `my-app-folder/`, `npm list --link=true` shows up empty. How can I get a list of the linked modules?

```
npm ls my_lib
my-app@3.1.0 /Users/path/my_project
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY my-lib@3.7.0 

npm ERR! missing: my-lib@3.7.0, required by my-app@3.1.0
```

This happens both with Node 8 and 10 and their respective npm versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I realized that `my-lib` was somehow linked globally

```
 $ npm ls -g --link=true --depth=0
/Users/apth/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib
└── my-lib@3.1.0 -> /Users/franzih/code/my-lib-folder
```

Unlinking it with `npm unlink -g my-lib` and linking it again worked and it now shows up as local link:

```
$ npm ls --link=true
my-app@3.1.0 /Users/path/code/my-app-folder
└─┬ my-app@3.7.0 -> /Users/path/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/my-lib-folder
  ├─┬ https-proxy-agent@2.2.1
  │ ├─┬ agent-base@4.2.1
  │ │ └─┬ es6-promisify@5.0.0
  │ │   └── es6-promise@4.2.4
  │ └─┬ debug@3.1.0
  │   └── ms@2.0.0
  └── node-fetch@2.2.0
```

Now `npm i` does not overwrite the link anymore. All good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "my-lib" was not linked globally, but I had to:

1. Uninstall it completely from "my-app" (`npm uninstall my-lib`)
2. `npm link my-lib` from "my-app", and then
3. Run `npm install my-lib` in "my-app"

Every other combination of steps did not work, and I did not find the uninstall or reinstall documented anywhere. Hope this helps anyone else running into this problem.